# Cordova Android 7.1.1 (Android API 27 - 8.1) app crashes

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

In my Ionic v1 Cordova application I been using the following plugin

> NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

, I can export the build and the app opens up on both 8.0(API 26)and 8.1 (API 27), but on 8.1 (API 27 and above) the app crashes when it try to ask permission.

I am using the following permission as per the plugin documentation

> permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE, 
>   permission.CAMERA,
>   permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
>   permission.BLUETOOTH,
>   permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED,
>   permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
>   permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

The same build works properly on Android 8.0 device

Output from the emulator

```
    10-18 09:54:51.269 I/zygote  (21486): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
10-18 09:54:51.284 D/FirebaseApp(21486): com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
10-18 09:54:51.335 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:51.641 I/chatty  (21486): uid=10086(com.brainsdesign.pooltrackr) RenderThread identical 6 lines
10-18 09:54:51.641 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:51.672 D/SystemWebChromeClient(21486): file:///android_asset/www/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.js: Line 51 : loadJobs
10-18 09:54:51.672 I/chromium(21486): [INFO:CONSOLE(51)] "loadJobs", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.js (51)
10-18 09:54:51.731 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:51.840 I/ActivityManager( 1633): START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10086
10-18 09:54:51.826 I/chatty  (21486): uid=10086(com.brainsdesign.pooltrackr) RenderThread identical 2 lines
10-18 09:54:51.826 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:51.892 D/SystemWebChromeClient(21486): file:///android_asset/www/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.js: Line 51 : getIds: {"userId":"79fa10c4-7996-4f2f-87bd-464676ca7c8a","pushToken":"ePmJOUT7ZrQ:APA91bE7DHAz54brBO5NYmtsxMLxpC669mWVj5JprtIgEqXMBdup9DnWL1YuQGB3INyvHScJCeIprAPa4Wy-JoIvdyUl9P92q6ce6FWq19UAjgqq3agg4EQ6EOs4f9bQA_ndgd71ZNlI"}
10-18 09:54:51.892 I/chromium(21486): [INFO:CONSOLE(51)] "getIds: {"userId":"79fa10c4-7996-4f2f-87bd-464676ca7c8a","pushToken":"ePmJOUT7ZrQ:APA91bE7DHAz54brBO5NYmtsxMLxpC669mWVj5JprtIgEqXMBdup9DnWL1YuQGB3INyvHScJCeIprAPa4Wy-JoIvdyUl9P92q6ce6FWq19UAjgqq3agg4EQ6EOs4f9bQA_ndgd71ZNlI"}", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.js (51)
10-18 09:54:51.893 D/SystemWebChromeClient(21486): file:///android_asset/www/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.js: Line 51 : userId = 79fa10c4-7996-4f2f-87bd-464676ca7c8a, pushToken = ePmJOUT7ZrQ:APA91bE7DHAz54brBO5NYmtsxMLxpC669mWVj5JprtIgEqXMBdup9DnWL1YuQGB3INyvHScJCeIprAPa4Wy-JoIvdyUl9P92q6ce6FWq19UAjgqq3agg4EQ6EOs4f9bQA_ndgd71ZNlI
10-18 09:54:51.893 I/chromium(21486): [INFO:CONSOLE(51)] "userId = 79fa10c4-7996-4f2f-87bd-464676ca7c8a, pushToken = ePmJOUT7ZrQ:APA91bE7DHAz54brBO5NYmtsxMLxpC669mWVj5JprtIgEqXMBdup9DnWL1YuQGB3INyvHScJCeIprAPa4Wy-JoIvdyUl9P92q6ce6FWq19UAjgqq3agg4EQ6EOs4f9bQA_ndgd71ZNlI", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/raven-js/dist/raven.js (51)
10-18 09:54:51.938 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:51.939 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:51.994 D/CordovaActivity(21486): Paused the activity.
10-18 09:54:51.999 D/CordovaWebViewImpl(21486): >>> loadUrl(javascript:cordova.plugins.backgroundMode._isActive=true;cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.fireEvent('activate',null);cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate(null);)
10-18 09:54:52.053 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633): Error showing notification for service
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633): java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=-2 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633):    at com.android.server.am.ServiceRecord$1.run(ServiceRecord.java:532)
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
10-18 09:54:52.126 W/ActivityManager( 1633):    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
10-18 09:54:52.151 I/chatty  (21486): uid=10086(com.brainsdesign.pooltrackr) RenderThread identical 2 lines
10-18 09:54:52.151 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:52.186 D/CordovaActivity(21486): Resumed the activity.
10-18 09:54:52.187 D/CordovaWebViewImpl(21486): >>> loadUrl(javascript:cordova.plugins.backgroundMode._isActive=false;cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.fireEvent('deactivate',null);cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.ondeactivate(null);)
10-18 09:54:52.192 D/AndroidRuntime(21486): Shutting down VM
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486): Process: com.brainsdesign.pooltrackr, PID: 21486
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=-2 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
10-18 09:54:52.195 E/AndroidRuntime(21486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
10-18 09:54:52.199 W/ActivityManager( 1633):   Force finishing activity com.brainsdesign.pooltrackr/.MainActivity
10-18 09:54:52.208 I/ActivityManager( 1633): Showing crash dialog for package com.brainsdesign.pooltrackr u0
10-18 09:54:52.245 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
10-18 09:54:52.245 E/eglCodecCommon(21486): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
```

Comment: Connect the device by USB and use Android Studio or `adb logcat` to capture the stacktrace from the native exception causing the crash, then please update your question with details of the native error.

Comment: Ok it looks `cordova-plugin-background-mode` (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) is breaking things on Cordova android 7.1.1  (Android 8.1 API 27). The plugin looks outdated, my recommendation is to remove the plugin if anyone building it for 8.1 devices